# How to keep endermen in an arena?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm making an arena minigame, and I realized a problem with the endermen: they would teleport out of the arena if left alone too long. I cannot fill in the area around the arena because the lobby is right next to it, and I really don't want to disable all the command blocks summoning the endermen. If the endermen cannot be kept in the arena, can they at least, through commands, be convinced to teleport back into the arena?

Comment: Use boats. Then they wander in the boats and get stuck. Or use water.

Comment: I'm sure Mojang added a command to summon them without teleportation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `rm` parameter allows you to obtains targets outside an area. You can use this to teleport endermen that left back to a certain location.

The following teleports endermen that are 50 blocks away or further from the specified coordinates back to the specified coordinates.

```
/tp @e[type=Enderman,x=10,y=64,z=10,rm=50] 10 64 10
```

Answer (score 0):

You have several options:

1) Move the arena to a far place, then fill out the surrounding space. To get to the arena use `/tp`.

2) Fill all exposed ground with slabs, water, …

3) Place a <kbd>repeat</kbd> and <kbd>alwyas active</kbd> command block with this command:

```
/testfor @e<kbd>[type=Enderman, x=X, y=Y, z=Z, r=ArenaWidth]
```

Then, place another <kbd>repeat</kbd>, <kbd>always active</kbd> command block testing if the 1st command block returned a false output. I'll use `XC`, `YC` and `ZC` as its coordinates:

```
/testforblock XC YC ZC minecraft:command_block -1 {SuccessCount:0}
```

Next to that command block place another one, this time <kbd>chain</kbd>:

```
/summon Enderman X Y Z
```

In both cases `X`, `Y` and `Z` above are the same coordinates.